# Test browser plugin performance, memory leaks, page loads, etc

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, plugins, google-chrome, profiling

We're having a series of browser plugins developed for us for Firefox, IE7/8/9, Chrome, and Safari, supported on Windows XP and up and on MAC OS X 10.5 and up.  Are there tools out there that we can use to objectively test performance?  For instance, how the plugins affect memory usage, CPU performance, page load time, etc?

Thanks SO!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ie9 U can see load time for plugins in Manage add-ons, but I don't think that there is a universal plug-in testing program.

I will suggest You to use some programs from [sysinternals suite](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062.aspx) to get advanced performance information's on windows platform.

Comment: Hi Nenad, which tools in sysinternals?

Comment: tools from process utilities category: Process Explorer and Process Monitor.

Answer (score 0):

I add to that that no all the computers have the same power in terms of processor operations, memory usage and consumption, and so. Win XP is different from Win 7 ie. I suggest you test your plugin in different configurations and also navigators, and then do some statistics calculation to achieve what you want.